# Why won't some Bluetooth keyboards pair in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, bluetooth

I've got three different Bluetooth keyboards that I use on my Windows 8.1 PC.

- Apple Wireless Keyboard
- Logitech K810
- Generic knockoff version on an Apple Wireless Keyboard by iClever

I've been using the knockoff Apple Wireless Keyboard for about six months, and yesterday I decided to switch to the Logitech K810.  I went to Devices and Printers in the Control Panel and selected Add a device.  I picked out the K810 from the list of available devices, and then I got a message saying

> "That didn't work", "Try again, and make sure your keyboard is still
>   discoverable."

I tried restarting my PC and that didn't work, so I tried adding my Apple Wireless Keyboard, and I got the same message that I got when attempting to add the K810. After getting this message, I have to restart the Bluetooh Support Service in order to get my device to show up when clicking on Add a device.

I have removed and readded the Knockoff keyboard a few times, so I know Bluetooth is working.  For some reason I cannot add either the Apple or Logitech keyboard.  Does anyone know how to get these keyboards paired successfully

In my Event Viewer, I can see a couple of messages:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        BTHUSB
Date:          12/2/2014 9:14:44 AM
Event ID:      3
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      dana
Description:
A command sent to the adapter has timed out. The adapter did not respond.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="BTHUSB" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32773">3</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-02T14:14:44.574266200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>419031</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>dana</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Binary>00000800010000000000000003000580570C00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000570C000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        BTHUSB
Date:          12/2/2014 9:14:40 AM
Event ID:      5
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      dana
Description:
The Bluetooth driver expected an HCI event with a certain size but did not receive it.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="BTHUSB" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49157">5</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-02T14:14:40.560627300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>419030</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>dana</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Binary>00000C000100000000000000050005C00E000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024000000040000000E040157</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        BTHUSB
Date:          12/2/2014 9:14:40 AM
Event ID:      28
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      dana
Description:
The local adapter does not support Bluetooth Low Energy.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="BTHUSB" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32773">28</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-02T14:14:40.560627300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>419029</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>dana</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Binary>0000000001000000000000001C000580000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        BTHUSB
Date:          12/2/2014 9:14:40 AM
Event ID:      18
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      dana
Description:
Windows cannot store Bluetooth authentication codes (link keys) on the local adapter. Bluetooth keyboards might not work in the system BIOS during startup.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="BTHUSB" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16389">18</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-02T14:14:40.545001800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>419028</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>dana</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Binary>00000800010000000000000012000540000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: The [K810 manual](http://www.logitech.com/assets/46511/bluetooth-illuminated-keyboard-k810.pdf) says it is only discoverable for 15 minutes after pressing its connect button. See also [Using Apple Wireless Keyboard on Windows](http://diophung.blogspot.sg/2013/06/using-apple-wireless-keyboard-on.html).

Comment: Any comments on the above?

Comment: No, no comments.  Of course I'm trying to connect within 15 minutes of pressing the connect button.

Comment: Good. Now do you have any comments on the procedure in the linked article?

Comment: I've done that as well.  Still no luck.

Comment: Verify in Device Manager / Network adapter that the correct driver is used.

Comment: I don't believe either keyboard shows up in the device manager.

Comment: I meant the wireless adapter. See also if Windows Update has optional updates that relate to hardware drivers.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but it's still not working.

Comment: I think you have a problem with the driver for the wireless adapter. It would help to know the adapter's model (BTH?) and what driver is assigned; for the driver go into Device Manager / Network adapter / right-click wireless adapter / Properties / Driver tab / Driver Details button, and post a screenshot of the dialog.

Comment: Having the exact same problem on a Windows 10 machine, Bluetooth works, a magic mouse and bluetooth speaker connect fine, it is my Logitech K810 that has the exact same "That didn't work", "Try again, and make sure your keyboard is still discoverable." when pairing, wish I could fine an answer, oh well, just have to buy a Logitech keyboard that works with a Unifying receiver

Answer (score 2):

Your reciever is not compatible with <kbd>GATT</kbd>.
 I would hazard a guess that the Apple keyboard was made in the last 3-4 years... and you provided model number for the logi which we know is also BTLE.

When Bluetooth devices sync up [they share "ATTribute profiles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles). These are basically just "codes" to say what functionality they are compatible with. The device in "pairing mode" announces it's profiles:

> My name is "phone headset" and I can do Stereo Bluetooth <kbd>A2DP</kbd> or normal headset <kbd>HSP</kbd>!

In this case perhaps the phone doesn't know stereo sound (it doesnt have <kbd>A2DP</kbd> profile) so it just adds the device as a headset. "secure pairing" (using a PIN) is optional here.

Keyboards are a LOT more basic - where they only have a generic profile which is on all the receivers, and <kbd>HID</kbd> which (for keyboards) needs a PIN to connect securely EVERY time.
 I suspect this is where it is breaking down, due to the other keyboards being more advanced:

1. PC searches for a device.
2. Device announces <kbd>ATT / GATT</kbd>(Bluetooth Low-Energy), <kbd>HID</kbd> (input device > keyboard)
3. The *First error* in that log just means the keyboard won't sync until the OS is booted each time (your adapter can't store the connection by itself). This is normal in cheaper units.
4. *Error 2:* PC doesnt have BTLE (defined in the <kbd>ATT</kbd>) so drops that profile and is now following standard procedure for the <kbd>HID</kbd> - get a PIN
5. *Error 3:* Device is **still** waiting on confirmation of <kbd>ATT</kbd> so the connection fails / times out. (Mexican stand-off)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a bad bluetooth driver which isn't rare in the Windows 8.1 environment. Try the following?

**Step 1: Uninstall the Bluetooth Device Drivers**

1. Press “Windows Logo” + “X” keys on the keyboard.
2. Click on “Device Manager” from that list.
3. Search for the Bluetooth device from the device list, right click on it and then select “Uninstall”. On the un-installation window, if you have an option: “Delete the driver software for this device” you may select that and then remove the corrupted drivers from the computer.
4. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete it and the restart the computer if prompted.
   After the restart, you may again open the Device Manager and then click on the “Scan for hardware changes” button at the top of the Device Manager window and check if Windows 8.1 detects the Bluetooth device and installs an appropriate driver for it automatically. If that happens, then check if it resolves the issue. If the issue persists, then go with the next step.

**Step 2: Registry Key**

5. Press Windows key + R and type Regedit.
6. Click on the plus signs (+) next to the following folders.
7. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
8. Right Click on the key in the Left Pane - Export it so you can reverse in case of a mistake. Save as Remove-Filters.reg (any name is ok with .reg as extension).
9. In the Right Pane look for any of these = UpperFilters - LowerFilters - UpperFilters.bak - LowerFilters.bak
10. If any exist Right Click on them – Delete.

***Important***: This section, method, or task contains steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore the registry.

1. Press Windows key + R.
2. Type “regedit” in the run box.
3. Locate and click the key or subkey that you want to back up.
4. Click the File menu, and then click Export.
5. In the Save in box, select the location where you want to save the backup copy to, and then type a name for the backup file in the File name box.
6. Click Save.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still can't add my keyboards

Comment: @RobertSeal I have about 20 class 4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318 Registry entries, is the one with the class "Keyboard" in right panel the one to be working with? Why are we Deleting UpperFilters, LowerFilters etc?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to pair the Logitech Bluetooth K810 keyboard on a Dell M6500 Precision 64bit Windows 10, running Bluetooth 2.0.

First I uninstalled my drivers and installed my drivers again. For my Dell M6500 Precision this was [Dell Wireless 365 Bluetooth Module Application](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=24T1W). I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07XZrn6ZxUM) to run the .exe which Windows 10 said was incompatible.

I then tried to upgrade to Bluetooth 4.0 using the latest Broadcom Drivers ("WIDCOMM® Bluetooth Windows® Software for Windows 10 & 8, 64-Bit"):
https://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth

This broke my Bluetooth driver in Device Manager giving me a warning icon and no Bluetooth.

I then ran the Broadcom Drivers .exe again to uninstall my failed Bluetooth 4.0 driver update, this caused some kind of rollback or update, to my previous drivers and all of the sudden my Logitech k810 paired, a bit of accidental luck. Strangely, or maybe not strangely, the Logitech K810 keyboard itself is listed in my Device Manager under Bluetooth:
[image]

I did not have the Logitech K810 pairing on, yet it paired on K810 Bluetooth 1. The K810 keyboard was paired, in the past, to my same Dell m6500 computer, before I did a fresh install of Windows 10 which cause the K810 to no longer pair.

It is possible that my Logitech K810 Keyboard was using Bluetooth 1 to pair to my Dell M6500 in the past, I cannot remember which K810 Bluetooth slot I was using before. After my fresh install of Windows 10, I had tried all 3 K810 Bluetooth slots and had the same "That didn't work", "Try again, and make sure your keyboard is still discoverable." error. Maybe, I was always trying to pair, and the K810 already had my Dell M6500 receiver information in Bluetooth slot 1 and this was causing some kind of conflict that was resolved when K810 Bluetooth slot 1 got to just got a change to connect to my Dell M6500 laptop, even after my clean install of Windows on the laptop, the K810 still had my laptop bluetooth receiver information on Bluetooth 1. I know its crazy.

The Logitech K810 is listed as a paired device under my Bluetooth devices.

Now that the last issue was that Logitech Setpoint did not detect my K810 keyboard. Which makes me think it was not the casue that K810 slot 1 just got a chance to do a clean uninterupted connect. So I removed the device from Windows Bluetooth Settings and then paired again, on K810 slot 1, not pushing my luck, and that got the K810 to show up in Logitech Setpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The [product support page for the Logitech K810](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/bluetooth-illuminated-keyboard-k810) indicates that it requires Bluetooth 3.0 or better to work correctly.  If your computer only has Bluetooth 2.0 connectivity, that explains why the Logitech keyboard won't work.

I couldn't find anything specific in the tech specs for the Apple wireless keyboard (it just says Bluetooth and that's it).

If this is an older computer (more than 3 or 4 years old), or a newer but exceptionally cheap one, it may be possible that your Bluetooth adapter just doesn't support the newer protocols.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bluetooth dongle, install the driver from the CD which came with it. Microsoft Generic driver won't work properly.

I am using Logitech K810 with HP Pavillion and a CSR4.0 Bluetooth dongle.